# GeForce MX130 nVidia driver?

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have a work laptop on which I've installed Debian Buster. The laptop comes with an nVidia GeForce MX130 3D renderer.

This is not a VGA adapter; it only does 3D. I've installed the nvidia GL libraries:

```
wouter@pc181009:~$ dpkg -l|grep nvidia
ii  glx-alternative-nvidia                  0.9.1                                amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libegl-nvidia0:amd64                    410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL library
ii  libegl-nvidia0:i386                     410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary EGL library
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:amd64           410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX library (GLVND variant)
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:i386            410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX library (GLVND variant)
ii  libgles-nvidia1:amd64                   410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 1.x library
ii  libgles-nvidia1:i386                    410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 1.x library
ii  libgles-nvidia2:amd64                   410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x library
ii  libgles-nvidia2:i386                    410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x library
ii  libglx-nvidia0:amd64                    410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary GLX library
ii  libglx-nvidia0:i386                     410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary GLX library
ii  libnvidia-cbl:amd64                     410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Vulkan ray tracing (cbl) library
ii  libnvidia-cfg1:amd64                    410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:amd64                 410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:i386                  410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-fatbinaryloader:amd64         410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA FAT binary loader
ii  libnvidia-glcore:amd64                  410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX core libraries
ii  libnvidia-glcore:i386                   410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX core libraries
ii  libnvidia-glvkspirv:amd64               410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Vulkan Spir-V compiler library
ii  libnvidia-glvkspirv:i386                410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA binary Vulkan Spir-V compiler library
ii  libnvidia-ml1:amd64                     410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1:amd64         410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA PTX JIT Compiler
ii  libnvidia-rtcore:amd64                  410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Vulkan ray tracing (rtcore) library
ii  nvidia-alternative                      410.104-1                            amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-driver                           410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA metapackage
ii  nvidia-driver-bin                       410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-driver-libs:amd64                410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)
ii  nvidia-driver-libs:i386                 410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES libraries)
ii  nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386            410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA metapackage (OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES 32-bit libraries)
ii  nvidia-egl-common                       410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL driver - common files
ii  nvidia-egl-icd:amd64                    410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-egl-icd:i386                     410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-installer-cleanup                20151021+9                           amd64        cleanup after driver installation with the nvidia-installer
ii  nvidia-kernel-common                    20151021+9                           amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-kernel-dkms                      410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source
ii  nvidia-kernel-support                   410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-legacy-check                     410.104-1                            amd64        check for NVIDIA GPUs requiring a legacy driver
ii  nvidia-modprobe                         410.93-1                             amd64        utility to load NVIDIA kernel modules and create device nodes
ii  nvidia-persistenced                     410.93-1                             amd64        daemon to maintain persistent software state in the NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-settings                         410.104-1                            amd64        tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-support                          20151021+9                           amd64        NVIDIA binary graphics driver support files
ii  nvidia-vdpau-driver:amd64               410.104-1                            amd64        Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix - NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-vulkan-common                    410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA Vulkan driver - common files
ii  nvidia-vulkan-icd:amd64                 410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA Vulkan installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-vulkan-icd:i386                  410.104-1                            i386         NVIDIA Vulkan installable client driver (ICD)
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia               410.104-1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Also, "update-glx --config glx" is set to use the nVidia drivers:

```
wouter@pc181009:~$ sudo LC_ALL=C update-glx --config glx
There are 3 choices for the alternative glx (providing /usr/lib/glx).

  Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/nvidia             100       auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/mesa-diverted      5         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia             100       manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/nvidia/bumblebee   95        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

yet, when I run "glxinfo", I see that the renderer is still using the Intel iGPU with the mesa library. Additionally, nvidia-settings just fails:

```
wouter@pc181009:~$ nvidia-settings -V

WARNING: NV-CONTROL extension not found on this Display.


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

What should I do to make the GL system use the nvidia GPU?

Comment: Hi there! Did you sort it out? I'm also getting the same behavior for that card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that this is a not-entirely-complete GPU. That is, it is a chipset that doesn't ship with a display connector, relying on an in-chip graphics chipset (i.e., Intel graphics) to do the display output. This is known as "NVidia OPTIMUS" (screaming by NVidia), and is supported under Linux through the "primus" driver.

In order for this to work, you need to install the `primus` package. Optionally you can also install `bumblebee`, although I'm not sure what the advantage of that would be (it uses primus behind the scenes).

Once the "primus" package has been installed, you can run applications on the NVidia GPU by way of primusrun:

```
primusrun glxinfo
```

will run `glxinfo` on the NVidia GPU, whereas

```
glxinfo
```

(i.e., `glxinfo` without the `primusrun` thing beforehand) will run `glxinfo` on the Intel GPU.

For things like steam, you can either run all of steam inside `primusrun`, or you can go to the per-game properties and add `primusrun` to the command line there.

Comment: Thank you! Just after installing primus, `nvidia-smi` started working. Linux Mint must be doing a better job at detecting this because the MX130 is working out of the box there.